# Criar nó no xml com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Olá, pessoal, eu to com um problema: Estou tentando criar um nó em um xml com jquery e não consigo... Eu tenho um arquivo xml o qual pego ele com ajax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dados>
    <usuarios>
        <usuario>
            <login>usuario</login>
            <senha>senha123</senha>
        </usuario>
    </usuarios>
</dados>
```

Eu consigo ler os nós do usuario facilmente. Porém não estou conseguindo adicionar outro usuário. Alguém pode me ajudar? Se houver alguma forma com javascript puro também não há problema. Obrigado desde já!

**Edit 1**:
O código jquery que estou usando é esse:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../xml/dados.xml",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            xml = data;
            var xmlDoc = $(xml);
            var element = xmlDoc.filter('usuarios');
            $(element).attr('type', 'vip');
            $(element).append("<usuario><login>usuario2</login><senha>senha321</senha></usuario>");
            $("body").append(xmlDoc);
        }
});
```

Eu achei este código procurando nesse forum do jquery:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/adding-xml-nodes-to-an-xmldocument-with-jquery-1-5

Comment: Você poderia postar o codigo javascript que esta utilizando para tentar adicionar usuario?

Comment: Vou editar o post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode manipular um `XML` da mesma forma que manipula um `HTML`.

então você apenas precisa fazer um seletor que obtinha o nó `usuarios` e adicionar conteúdo à ele.

```js
var xmlText = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <dados>
      <usuarios>
          <usuario>
              <login>usuario1</login>
              <senha>senha123</senha>
          </usuario>
      </usuarios>
  </dados>
`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, "text/xml");

var xml = $(xmlDoc);
var usuarios = $("usuarios", xmlDoc);

usuarios.append(`
  <usuario>
      <login>usuario2</login>
      <senha>senha321</senha>
  </usuario>
`);

console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

o código exibido acima usando apenas JavaScript.

```js
var xmlText = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <dados>
      <usuarios>
          <usuario>
              <login>usuario1</login>
              <senha>senha123</senha>
          </usuario>
      </usuarios>
  </dados>
`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, "text/xml");
var usuarios = xmlDoc.documentElement.querySelector("usuarios");

var usuarioText = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <usuario>
      <login>usuario2</login>
      <senha>senha321</senha>
  </usuario>
`;

var usuarioDoc = parser.parseFromString(usuarioText, "text/xml");
usuarios.appendChild(usuarioDoc.documentElement);

console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Opa! Pra mim funcionou dessa segunda maneira! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso resolve seu problema

```html
$.get('teste.xml', function(response){
   var xml = response;
   var usuarios = xml.querySelector('usuarios');
   var novoUsuario = xml.createElement('usuario');
   var login = xml.createElement('login');
   var senha = xml.createElement('senha');

   login.appendChild( xml.createTextNode("geeksilva") );
   senha.appendChild( xml.createTextNode("123") );
   novoUsuario.appendChild(login);
   novoUsuario.appendChild(senha);
   usuarios.appendChild(novoUsuario)


  }, 'xml');
```

Fiz usando javascript puro mesmo, veja que basta usar o DOM que se usa normalmente para o **HTMLDocument**. A diferença é o objeto que é **XMLDocument** mas a forma de manipular o DOM segue os mesmos princípios